# Analysing Percentage Data inc. Phylogenetic Bias?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, percentage, phylogeny

I'm attempting to analyse a percentage / proportional (derived from count) response variable across several species, allowing for consideration of phylogenetic signal. I'd like to model this data against continuous and/or categorical explanatory variables. Ignoring the non-independence of the individual data points (i.e. 'non-phylo'), the standard approach (in the case of continuous predictor) would be to undertake a non-binary logistic regression. Easy.

I'm aware of the assorted existing approaches used to fit phylogenetic linear models, glms etc. to continuous variables, and a phylogenetic logistic model for binary variables (per `phyloglm` in the `phylolm` R package), though as far as I'm aware none adequately handle my case. Logistic regression via `phyloglm` doesn't allow for dummy variables, for example. My data doesn't approximate anything resembling a normal distribution or a continuous measure, so shoehorning my data into a standard phylogenetic linear regression etc. won't work.

Does anything exist for this sort of analysis? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!